# OR condition not working

Tags: query, mysql

I am using the following code to search some data from WordPress database, but when first condition is false then OR condition is not working.

```
 $where .= ' AND ((' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE '.$search_term.') || ('. $wpdb->postmeta. '.meta_value LIKE '.$search_term.'))';
```

Comment: Are you using post_where filter ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Comment: yes i am using post_where filter

Comment: Try to make tout logic before not on the where .=

Answer (score 0):

The problem is strictly with your query... or to be more precise, with your misunderstanding of your query ;)

You've put `||` in there and you assume it is `OR` operator, but... [depending on configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) of server it can act as `OR` or... string concatenation ;)

So change it to `OR` and it should work fine, I guess...